# differentiating between correlation and a temporal relationship

Tags: idioms, mathematics

Could you please through two simple example show me the difference between these?

1. a significant correlation between the occurrence of two phenomena (both phenomena generally occur together), or
2. a temporal relationship between the two (one event occurred after another).

Answer (score 1):

**correlation**

Two variables that change value together, either both in the same direction (positive c.) or in the opposite direction (negative c.).

- When the temperature rises, more ice cream is sold. (positive correlation)
- When the temperature rises, fewer winter coats are sold. (negative correlation).

**Temporal relationship**

A chain of events with event A being followed by event B

- After finishing High School I started College.
- First we get married, then we start a family.
- The clouds are building up, there will soon be a thunderstorm.

Comment: Forgot one classic example for temporal: January, February, March,...

Comment: Also, correlation is not causation.  When the trees shake back and forth, the wind blows.  (positive correlation, but the trees don't cause the wind.)